# Should I install a floating engineered wood floor over my particle underlayment floor

Tags: installation, engineered-flooring, particle-board

I currently going to install a floating engineered wood flooring. The existing flooring consists of 3/4" plywood and a 1/2" particle board on top of the plywood. There's currently carpet on top of the particle board. My question is should I install the floating engineered wood of top of the particle board (as the particle board is in great shape) or should I remove the particle board? It looks like the particle board is glued to the plywood and might be a big mess to get out.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd feel comfortable having a floor of particle board. I know how it reacts with water and moisture and it seems it could be a weak link in your flooring.  Maybe some of our 4th generation carpenters can chime in.

Comment: are you sure it’s particle board or is it OSB?  Can you post a picture? What is the grade of the plywood subfloor? What is the size and spacing and span of floor supports?